# How do I Install NuGet Package

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, nuget

I am working on Visual Studio 2010.

I want to install the package into my vs2010 for WPF application.

I want to install the following package:

[image]

The above package version is : **Wpf AutoGrid 1.3.0**

While installation I am getting following error:

[image]

I also tried with other versions also but didn't get anything.

Comment: Did you intend to use the Client Profile of .net 4 in your main project?

Comment: @BradleyUffner, No! There is no any special purpose.

Comment: The client profile was designed to use a smaller, more lightweight version .net so that end users didn't have to download the entire .net framework.  Try changing it to the full version.

Comment: Make sure you have updated Nuget Package Manager to the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**None of the other provided solution will work** because the Nuget package of WPFAutoGrid only have binaries compiled on .Net 4.5 even if you change your project's target framework from `4.0 client profile` to `4.0 full` framework version. Now you have two choices

1. Either [download the project](https://github.com/carbonrobot/wpf-autogrid) or [Fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) it and try to compile it with your project's target framework 4.0. This might break the build so you would endup fixing the broken issues in worst case scenario. If it works use that library in your project happily.
2. Or Raise an [Issue](https://github.com/carbonrobot/wpf-autogrid/issues) on github source of WPFAutoGrid to request update of Nuget package to include a .Net 4.0 libraries.

Comment: Hey I have installed that package in 4.5 but can't able use it in `XAML`. I have used `<AutoGrid></AutoGrid>` in place of `<Grid></Grid>` but getting an error `AutoGrid is not supported in WPF`.

Comment: I'm not sure about this error. Since its completely different error now May be you should start a separate question and also raise this issue on [Github](https://github.com/carbonrobot/wpf-autogrid/issues) with proper details.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Visual Studio 2010 RTM which still not included with .NET Framework 4.0, the package WPF Auto Grid require at least .NET Framework 4.0 in order to work. So I guess you can install .NET Framework 4.0 by yourself or you can use newer version of Visual Studio which by default already installed with .NET Framework 4.0.

Let me know and mark it as an answer if it helps you :)

Comment: The nuget error says his project is already targeting the 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your main project is targeting the [Client Profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912(v=vs.110).aspx) of .net 4.0.  Try changing your main project to build against the full profile.

See this MSDN page for specific step-by-step on how to change it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I have change target framework from .Net Framework 4 Client Profile to .Net Framework but still getting an same error.